# class EntitySetController missing with web api v2.2 and OData v4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, signalr, odata

I am following this video:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Belgium-2013/25

I am building an asp.net web api v 2.2 with Odata v4.

In my controller i am supposed to use 'EntitySetController':
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj890573(v=vs.118).aspx

for some reason it is not available when i try to put it in code.

i am including the: using System.Web.OData and i can use ODataController but it doesn't recognize 'EntitySetController'.

Is it possible that it is not available anymore in api v2.2 or Odata v4? since the tutorial i gave at the beginning is old?

i have installed the packes with this command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Odata
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked with OData engineering team, who confirmed that EntitySetController is removed from Web API 2.2. Please check [What's New in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22) for documentation.